# Is it better to assign boolean to local variable and reuse it or duplicate comparison using if?

Tags: c#, performance, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, boolean

Imagine I have this code(Razor syntax):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
@{
    var i = 0;
    foreach (var notify in @Model)
    {
        if (i > 1) // <------ First comparison 
        {
            <text>setTimeout(function() {</text>
        }

        <text>
        // JavaScript
        </text>

        if (i > 1) // <------  Second same comparison
        {
            <text>}, 1000 * @i);</text>
        }

        i++;
    }
}
</script>
```

Notice that `int i` is compared twice. Is it better to assing result of first comparison to local variable and then check it's value or do a second simple comparison? Like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
@{
    var i = 0;
    foreach (var notify in @Model)
    {
        bool higherThanOne = i > 1;
        if (higherThanOne)
        {
            <text>setTimeout(function() {</text>
        }

        <text>
        // JavaScript
        </text>

        if (higherThanOne)
        {
            <text>}, 1000 * @i);</text>
        }

        i++;
    }
}
</script>
```

I came across similiar situation many times and I'm not sure what's better. I want to avoid assigning code to variables because of unfriendly Razor + JavaScript concatenation syntax.

Comment: 'better' in what sense? Answer that and you will have answered your own question.

Comment: Performance, convention, code readability.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this case, yes, to document, what this magic condition means:

```
bool wrapInTimeout = i > 1;
```

And don't call it `higherThanOne`. That would be an unhelpful name.

Name your variables according to what they represent, not according to how they were computed.

Comment: I'll probably remember this naming convention. Thanks for answer.

Answer (score 1):

The comparison is very simple in your case so I don't see any advantage of using a temporary variable, however, if you do have more comparisons that are the same then you might want to use that variable as it simplified code structure and readability.

Also I noticed that you can actually combine the two conditions into one if the same javascript function is called every time:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
@{
    var i = 0;
    foreach (var notify in @Model)
    {
        if (i > 1) // <------ First comparison 
        {
            <text>setTimeout(myFunction, 1000 * @i);</text>
        }

        i++;
    }

    <text>function myFunction(){ //your code here, if the same for all models }</text>
}
</script>
```

Comment: This code isn't the same, it's actually based on different properties, but thanks for answer.

Comment: again it depends, if you can pass the property values as parameters to myFunction, it would still be a better option as it also allows you to move that javascript piece into .js file and create better separation.

Comment: You're right. I'll probably create another function and make calls.